# Como resuelvo este tipo de ejercicio en pseint

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Con base en el enunciado debe presentar una algoritmo modular (sin usar arreglos) que satisfaga los objetivos indicados a continuación. ENUNCIADO: Captar los nombres y las edades de 10 personas  cumpliendo con los siguientes objetivos:
1.- Implementar ciclo Mientras

2.- Determinar y mostrar la edad promedio de todas las personas

3.- Determinar y mostrar el porcentaje de las personas menores de edad

4.- Determinar y mostrar la menor edad y el nombre de la 1era persona que la tiene

5.- Determinar y mostrar la mayor edad y el nombre de la 1era persona que la tiene

La condicion es que no use arreglo, sino que todo sea con varios subprocesos usando ciclo mientras

```
Algoritmo MayorMenor
Entrada(nombre,edad,acum)
PromedioEdad(edad,acum,prom)
FinAlgoritmo
SubProceso Entrada(nombre por referencia, edad por referencia,cont por referencia)
i=1
cont=0
Mientras i<=3 
    Mostrar "Ingrese el nombre de la ",i "°persona: " Sin Saltar
    Leer nombre
    Mostrar "Ingrese la edad de la ",i "°persona: " Sin Saltar
    Leer edad
    i=i+1
    acum=acum+edad
FinMientras
FinSubProceso

SubProceso PromedioEdad(edad,acum,prom Por Referencia)
prom=acum/3
FinSubProceso
```

Comment: podrías agregar lo que haz intentado?

Comment: Algoritmo MayorMenorEntrada(nombre,edad,acum)
 PromedioEdad(edad,acum,prom)
FinAlgoritmo

SubProceso Entrada(nombre por referencia, edad por referencia,cont por referencia)
 i=1
 cont=0
 Mientras i<=3 
  Mostrar "Ingrese el nombre de la ",i "°persona: " Sin Saltar
  Leer nombre
  Mostrar "Ingrese la edad de la ",i "°persona: " Sin Saltar
  Leer edad
  i=i+1
  acum=acum+edad
 FinMientras
FinSubProceso

SubProceso PromedioEdad(edad,acum,prom Por Referencia)
 prom=acum/3
FinSubProceso

Comment: dale editar a tu pregunta y añade todo lo que haz puesto en la zona de comentarios

Comment: He intentando usando el mientras para que recorrra las variables en otros subprocesos donde buscare al menor y al meyor con su respectivo nombre, pero solo em da el ultimo valor que ha tomado la varaible, entonces tengo la duda es en como recorrerlo para que tome en cuenta los valores

Comment: ¿Qué perfil usas?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes entender bien la diferencia entre paso por valor y paso por referencia.

Si el valor de una variable lo piensas cambiar después, usa el paso por referencia, si no usa paso por valor.

Estoy usando el perfil `FCA-UNAM` que es un poco más estricto que el que tienes, así que espero sirva para que te quede más claro en pseudo.

La edad acumulada la usaremos para los cálculos posteriores, así que ese valor lo pasamos por referencia al leerlo, así al salir del subproceso no perderemos ese valor.

Los nombres como verás son irrelevantes en los demás pasos, así que reducimos su ámbito para que los nombres vivan solamente en el subproceso entrada y saliendo de ese subproceso se borren.

```
Algoritmo MayorMenor
    definir acum Como Entero;
    acum=0;
    Entrada(acum);
    PromedioEdad(acum);
FinAlgoritmo

SubProceso Entrada(acum por referencia)
    Definir nombre como Cadena;
    Definir edad como Entero;
    Definir i como Entero;
    i=1;
    Mientras i<=3 
        Mostrar "Ingrese el nombre de la ",i "°persona: " Sin Saltar;
        Leer nombre;
        Mostrar "Ingrese la edad de la ",i "°persona: " Sin Saltar;
        Leer edad;
        i=i+1;
        acum=acum+edad;
    FinMientras
FinSubProceso

SubProceso PromedioEdad(acum)
    Definir prom Como Real;
    prom=acum/3;
    Escribir "el promedio de edades es " prom;
FinSubProceso
```

Otras cosas que puedes notar en este avance, es que nombre y edad los estoy definiendo afuera del ciclo while, esto no es casualidad, es una optimización para evitar crear nuevos objetos dentro de un ciclo, que en un programa real te ahorrará el tiempo de reservar dinámicamente memoria para tu variables en cada iteración.

Otro consejo que podrás percibir es que los parámetros de los métodos son minimalistas, no pases más cosas de las necesarias, eso te permitirá visualizar los subprocesos como si fueran funciones matemáticas y no como una tediosa rutina.